# pusher 403 forbidden - Laravel Broadcasting

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

I have an 403 forbidden error when using pusher, everything looks correct but I still face this error!

After the user create the order a new notification should be created:

```
    $order->doctor->user->notify(new AppointmentNotification($checkOrder, $user));
```

in the AppointmentNotification file:

```
public function via(object $notifiable): array
    {
        return ['broadcast'];
    }

    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'title' => 'Appointment Reservation',
            'body' => 'New Appointment Reservation!',
            'icon' => 'fadeIn animated bx bx-health',
            'url' => route('doctor.appointments'),
            'doctorId' => $notifiable->id, 
        ]);
    }
```

The channel:

```
Broadcast::channel('Models.User.{doctorId}', function ($user, $doctorId) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $doctorId;
});
```

The bootstrap and js files countains:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ? import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST : `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

window.Echo.private(`App.Models.User.${doctorId}`)
    .notification(function(data){
        alert(data.body)
    })
```

And finally Im defining the doctorId in the layout and calling the Js file:

```
<script>
        const doctorId = "{{ optional(Auth::user()->doctor)->user_id }}";
    </script>
    <script>
        {!! Vite::content('resources/js/app.js')  !!}
</script>
```

Everything looks correct, I need you help, thanks.

I have tried to create event, and I faced the same error!

Comment: Show broadcastOn function

Comment: Im using toBroadcast directly without broadcastOn

Comment: Is your 403 error coming from your server, or from pusher.com?